# Equivalent laravel relationship query for this join

Tags: laravel, eloquent, custom-fields

this is my query

```
$personnel_info = \DB::table('assigns AS a')
        ->join('boxes AS b','b.id','=', 'a.box_id')
        ->join('positions AS p','p.id','=', 'b.position_id')
        ->select('a.id','b.id AS box_id','p.id as position_id','p.title','a.status','a.end_date')
        ->where('a.personnel_id','=',$personnel_id)
        ->get();
```

and this realtionship for boxes:

```
    class Boxes extends Model
{
    public function position()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Positions');
    }

    public function assign()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Assigns', 'box_id');
    }
}
```

how to use eloquent query(also realtionship) for replace DB facade query?
i want select some field for tables.without define fileds in boxes model
tnx

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$personnel_info = Assign::with('box.position')
->where('personnel_id', $personnel_id)
->get();
```

Then `dd($personnel_info)` to see everything  that was returned. If you don't like the values, then add your `select()` clause.